# out of memory allocating 1073745919 bytes

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I am trying to upload a car mesh in QML but the mesh.obj(under qrc) apparently is too big, I added CONFIG +=resources_big to my .pro file but nothing changed.then I tried to call it from outside the application but it doesn't work. how can I resolve this? I am using qt5.10 and MinGW as a compiler.

Comment: How big is the mesh file? Are you sure the problem is the file being big? What is the error you are getting? When are you facing this problem? Your current question doesn't give any info, how can we answer that?

Comment: the error is : out of memory allocating 1073745919bytes and the mesh I am trying to upload is about 55MB .it's about size because when i uploaded a part of it (1Mo) it worked.

Comment: Have you tried http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2016-March/021579.html ? Please check it and tell us if it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to put huge files in a qrc resource. That will result in a significant overhead. It will bloat your executable file, which takes up RAM, it will have to be additionally loaded into ram in Qt's resource virtual file system, an you will still to load it from there into ram in order to use it.

Put it out on the file system in the app folder, where you can load it from disk straight into RAM, significantly reducing memory usage.

Also, 3d meshes lend themselves to compression really well, and Qt's `QByteArray` has compression support, so you might want to put that to work to reduce the deployment footprint.

Comment: I put it on the file system in the app folder and I tried to load it but nothing is displayed.it seems like the mesh is only displayed when it's in qrc resource (in qrc , I tried to display a part of it and it worked ),and I don't know why it couldn't be loaded from local directory path.if anyone can help

Comment: Because your project searches for qrc files by default, you have to tell it that you want to load a file from the file system by prepending `file:///` to the file path.

Comment: thank you ! I didn't realize that I have to prefix the url to force it to look at the local file system.